# Reliability: Path/Cut Vector Technique in Python

Tags: python, string, reliability

I have a list, `lst`, that contains only **0's** and **1's** of length **n**.

The list represents either a cut vector or a path vector, from reliability analysis, which may or may not be minimal cut/path vectors themselves.

The elements within the list represent separate variables, say **x1**, **x2**, and **x3** and the length of the list, **n**, represents the number of variables being represented.

For example, the list `[0, 1, 1]` represents 3 variables, **x1**, **x2**, and **x3**.

Given the input, `lst`, I want to return a *list* or *string* that is guided by the following rules.

### Rules:

1. If **x<sub>i</sub>** = 1:

   a. return **(x<sub>i</sub>)**
2. else if **x<sub>i</sub>** = 0:

   b. return: **(1 - x<sub>i</sub>)**

### Examples:

`[0, 1] => [1-X1, X2]` or `"1-X1, X2"`

`[1, 0] => [X1, 1-X2]` or `"X1, 1-X2"`

`[0, 1, 1] => [1-X1, X2, X3]` or `"1-X1, X2, X3"`

`[1, 1, 1] => [X1, X2, X3]` or `"X1, X2, X3"`

### My Code:

```
def get_function(path_vector):
    lst = []
    for item in path_vector:
        if "0" in item:
            print("1-", item, sep="")
            lst.extend(["1-", item])
        else:
            print(item)
            lst.append(item)
    print(lst)
    expr = "*".join(lst)
    return expr
```

### Goal:

The eventual goal is to join the items in the new list - separated by a `*` - and input them into a function from the **sympy** library.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Hi there and welcome. It looks like you're asking for general help. Usually we like it most when you've narrowed down the question to a specific problem you've been having rather than asking for help on how to do the problem as a whole. If this is for a class and you're unsure of where to start, I'd suggest reaching out to classmates or a TA for the tips you're looking for.

Comment: What should I include to make the question better?

Comment: `item` is value `0` or `1` but you need its position on list to create string `Xposition` - so you have to  count elements when you use `for`-loop  or use `enumerate()`.

Comment: if you use list of itegers `[0, 1]` then you should compare integers `if item == 0:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` has values `0` or `1` but you need its position on list to create string `1-X{position}` or `X{position}`

You may use `enumarate(..., 1)` to get its position on list.

Because you have integer values then you should compare integers `if item == 0:`

---

Minimal working code which use list `examples` to generate string and compare with expected result

```
def get_function(path_vector):
    lst = []

    for position, item in enumerate(path_vector, 1):
        if item == 0:
            text = f"1-X{position}" 
        else:
            text = f"X{position}" 
        lst.append(text)
        print('text:', text)

    print('lst:', lst)
    expr = "*".join(lst)

    return expr
    
# --- main --- 
    
examples = [    
    ([0, 1], "1-X1*X2"),
    ([1, 0], "X1*1-X2"),
    ([0, 1, 1], "1-X1*X2*X3"),
    ([1, 1, 1], "X1*X2*X3"),
]

for data, expected_result in examples:
    result = get_function(data)
    print(data, expected_result, result, expected_result==result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I never realized the "enumerate" function existed.